How to attach slider to the bottom of bar in Compose?
I want to make a spotify clone app, I am trying to build a similar bottom bar like the image, but i were unable to make slider fill max width (without padding from left, right, bottom).
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    /**
     * The [AudioViewModel] instance is obtained via the [viewModels] delegate,
     * which uses the activity as the ViewModelStoreOwner.
     */
    private val viewModel: AudioViewModel by viewModels()

    /**
     * The [onCreate] method is called when the activity is starting.
     * It sets up the UI content and associates it with the activity.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down
     * then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in [onSaveInstanceState].
     * Otherwise it is null.
     */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AudioAppTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                   HomeScreen(progress = 0f,
                       onProgress = {},
                    isAudioPlaying= true,
                    currentPlayingAudio = viewModel.audioList[0],
                    audioList = viewModel.audioList,
                    onStart={},
                    onItemClick= {  },
                    onNext= { })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    progress: Float,
    onProgress:(Float) -> Unit,
    isAudioPlaying: Boolean,
    currentPlayingAudio: Audio,
    audioList: List<Audio>,
    onStart:() -> Unit,
    onItemClick: (Int)->Unit,
    onNext: ()->Unit
) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBarPlayer(
                progress = progress,
                onProgress = onProgress,
                isAudioPlaying = isAudioPlaying,
                audio = currentPlayingAudio,
                onStart = onStart,
                onNext = onNext,
            )
        }
    ){

    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomBarPlayer(
    progress: Float,
    onProgress: (Float) -> Unit,
    isAudioPlaying: Boolean,
    audio: Audio,
    onStart: () -> Unit,
    onNext: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface{
        val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        var sliderPosition by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .height(60.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Gray),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){
            ArtistInfo(audio = audio)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Slider(
                value = sliderPosition,
                onValueChange = { sliderPosition =it },
                valueRange = 0f..5f,
                onValueChangeFinished = {
                    // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
                },
                colors = SliderDefaults.colors(
                    inactiveTrackColor = Color.Gray,
                ),
                thumb = {
                    SliderDefaults.Thumb( //androidx.compose.material3.SliderDefaults
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        thumbSize = DpSize(0.dp,0.dp)
                    )
                },

                )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalGlideComposeApi::class)
@Composable
fun ArtistInfo(
    audio: Audio,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        GlideImage(
            model = R.drawable.image1,
            contentDescription = "Audio Image",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(56.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(4.dp))

        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            Text(
                text = audio.artistName,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
                maxLines = 1
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(1.dp))

            Text(
                text = audio.audioName,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}


BottomBarExample
My current output
I tried to use LinearProgressIndicator, but it did not work. And it was a bad solution for the purpose.

The BottomAppBar Composable implements the Material3 specifications for padding wich is 16.dp. You can't easily change it.
If you want to get rid of any default padding, I would suggest to use a Surface instead:
@Composable
fun BottomBarPlayer(
    progress: Float,
    onProgress: (Float) -> Unit,
    isAudioPlaying: Boolean,
    audio: Audio,
    onStart: () -> Unit,
    onNext: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(56.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}

Also, a LinearProgressIndicator might be more suitable in your case:
LinearProgressIndicator(
    progress = { 0.5f }
)


thanks for the solution it were very helpful, i read the document you provided i were able to attach the slider to bottom, but i weren't able to fill max width. (there is padding from left and right). i edit the code and provide the whole hierarchy of code.

@FatimaJamal I tested it and I see no padding. The Slider goes to the very left and tight edges of the screen. Can you include a screenshot of your current output in your post? Also note that on stackoverflow, you should not edit your question to ask for more things than you initially asked.

Also see my edited post. A LinearProgressIndicator might be more suitable in your case than a Slider.

Thanks for the note regarding editing the question. I have provided a screenshot, i'm testing the code on Samsung s4(5,1), For the LinearProgressIndicator, i want the user to be able to change current position of song, but with progressIndicator i were unable to achieve this.
